# How to add single item to arraylist for multiple time with out using for loop

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my application contains one Arraylist which i am adding value for every minute.

Initially I want to add one value for thousands time for that arraylist for that my code is

```
int count = 30000; Arraylist mylist = new Arraylist();for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
{
    mylist.add("4.5");
}
```

In the above code it is taking large time to complete the for loop and my app is getting slow .
Is there any alternate way to add the value to array list fastly with one click?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Collections`'s `static <T> List<T> nCopies(int n, T o)`:

```
List<String> list = Collections.nCopies("4.5",count);
```

However, that would create an immutable `List<String>`. In order to obtain a mutable `List`, you'll have to pass that list to `ArrayList`'s constructor, so I'm not sure the end result will be much faster than your current loop.

```
List<String> mylist = new Arraylist<>(Collections.nCopies("4.5",count));
```

Comment: Thanks for u r reply...one more small doubt how to add values from index 2

Comment: @VenkataKishoreA What do you mean? Do you want index 0 and index 1 to remain 0? You can set them to 0 after initializing the ArrayList.

Comment: yes i am adding mylist.add(5.0),mylist.add(1.0); and myList = new ArrayList<Double>(Collections.<Double>nCopies(secondsinfo, 4.5));but arraylist is starting from 4.5

Comment: @VenkataKishoreA Add `mylist.set(0,0.0);mylist.set(1,0.0);`